# Algebraic Expression making perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For what value of $a$ and $b$ would $$x^4+2x^3+ax^2+bx+9$$ 
Would give perfect square?
I have found $a=7$ and $b=6$.
How many more are there?
Can we find all of it ?

Answer (score 1):

The given polynomial is a perfect square if and only if 
$$x^4+2x^3+ax^2+bx+9=(x^2+Ax+B)^2$$
for some $A,B$. That is, after expanding and comparing the coefficients, 
$$2x^3+ax^2+bx+9=2Ax^3+(2B+A^2)x^2+2ABx+B^2
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
A=1\\
2B+A^2=a\\
2AB=b\\
B^2=9
\end{cases}$$
Now it should be easy to find ALL the values of $a$ and $b$ that give you a perfect square.

Comment: @Georgecarlin Have you found ALL the values of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1):

Some hints: if it is a a perfect square it has to the square of a second degree polynomial. It is clear that the leading coefficient has to be $1$. Also the constant term has to be $\pm 3$ so that we get the constant term $9$ when you square. So equate your polynomial with $(x^{2}+\alpha x\pm 3)^{2}$ and compare coefficients. Can you take it from here?